# What is the error in this part of my code that is related to the time in the event calendar app? I'm new to flutter

Tags: flutter, date, time, calculator

What is the error in this part of my code that is related to the time in the event calendar app? I'm new to flutter.
this is my code screen :

```
 [Future pickFromDateTime({required bool pickDate}) async {
    final date = await pickDateTime(fromDate, pickDate: pickDate);
  }

  Future<DateTime?> pickDateTime(
    DateTime initialDate, {
    required bool pickDate,
    DateTime? firstDate,
  }) async {
    if (pickDate) {
      final date = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: initialDate,
          firstDate: firstDate ?? DateTime(2020, 1),
          lastDate: DateTime(2101));

      if (date == null) return null;

      final time =
          Duration(hours: initialDate.hour, minutes: initialDate.minute);
      return date.add(time);
    } else {
      final timeOfDay = await showTimePicker(
          context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(initialDate));

      if (timeOfDay == null) return null;
      final Date = DateTime(initialDate.year, initialDate.month);
      final Time =
          Duration(hours: initialDate.hour, minutes: initialDate.minute);
                return date.add(time);
    }
  }][1]
```

Comment: I have "Undefined name 'date' & 'time'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name." message

Error in =>         return date.add (time);

Answer (score 0):

Careful with your variable names. You declared those variables as ´Date´ and ´Time´, but you are trying to use them by calling ´date´ and ´time´.

Call your variables with lowercase.

```
  final date = DateTime(initialDate.year, initialDate.month);
  final time =
      Duration(hours: initialDate.hour, minutes: initialDate.minute);
            return date.add(time);
```